# How to add empty item to Netbeans JComboBox?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

I want to add an empty item as a default choice to my JComboBox. Not in source code btw, but in the properties part of the *design* section. The result should be:

1

2 Apple

3 Potato

4 Tomato

Comment: Don't actually play with Swing much, but how about using empty String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Right click the JComboBox, Properties, selectedIndex, then type in -1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have "none" as your first element in the array and then if the user selects none, you can code accordingly in the backend.

Another option is that you can use:
JCombobox.setSelectedItem(-1);

Try both!